# CodenameOne - Get selected values from multilist

Tags: codenameone

How can I get only the selected values from the MultiList control ?
Please provide me with sample code.

Answer (score 2):

```
Map<String, Object> value = (Map<String, Object>)list.getSelectedItem();
```

Will return the selected item (the one you clicked). I'm assuming you used the check box list for which you should use something like:

```
ListModel<Map<String, Object>> model (ListModel<Map<String, Object>>)list.getModel();
int size = model.getSize();
for(int iter = 0 ; iter < size ; iter++) {
    Map<String, Object> value = model.getItemAt(iter);
    String selected = (String)value.get("selected");
    if(selected != null && selected.equals("true")) {
         ... add to list of selected items
    }
}
```

Comment: This didn't work for me. (String) value.get("selected") is always null.

Comment: So you vote the answer down instead of asking nicely?

Comment: Instead of asking what nicely? Voting is central to the model of providing quality questions and answers here at stackoverflow. This answer is incorrect. Voting down an answer signals to the rest of the community that this post is of low quality. Should you update your answer with a code snippet that works properly I would gladly turn my downvote into an upvote.

Comment: The answer is correct, notice my rep count and bio. Its polite to first check whether you might have gotten something wrong rather than assume.

Answer (score 1):

In answer above change line 1 to the following: added '=' sign
ListModel> model = (ListModel>)list.getModel();

change line 5: 
the word selected in quotes "selected" must match emblemname in your GUI for checkbox or if you created multilist it must match the name you used in your code for checkbox